# Trying to write to a .DAT file but doesn't seem to be doing anything?

Tags: java

I used this code in a different application to write a name and highscore onto the file for my game. Now i'm using this code to get a name and password from a .DAT file and be able to add a new user and password. Here's the .DAT file.

```
michael123
speaker123
katherine123
motor123
username
password
```

Here's the code. Reading the file works fine but writing to it does nothing at all and i'm unsure why.

```
InputStream file;
BufferedReader fileStream;
FileWriter fileWriter;
BufferedWriter fileWrite;
String temp = "";
int users = 0;

public void readUserInfo() throws IOException {
    try {
        file = Board.class.getResourceAsStream("users.DAT");
        fileStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {

            temp = fileStream.readLine();
            Board.username[i] = temp.trim();
            temp = fileStream.readLine();
            Board.password[i] = temp.trim();

    }
    //Close
    fileStream.close();
    file.close();
}

public void addUser() throws IOException {

    fileWriter = new FileWriter(Board.class.getResource("users.DAT").getFile(),true);
    fileWrite = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    System.out.println("Users : " + users);
    //Skip already created users
   for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {

        fileWrite.newLine();
        fileWrite.append(Board.username[i]);
        fileWrite.newLine();
        fileWrite.append(Board.password[i]);

    } 
    System.out.println("Adding" + Board.username[users] + " : " + Board.password[users]);
    //Add user  
    fileWrite.newLine();
    fileWrite.append(Board.username[users]);
    fileWrite.newLine();
    fileWrite.append(Board.password[users]);
    //Close
    fileWrite.close();
    System.out.println("Closed fileWrite");
}
```

I'm using netbeans. The file being read from is in the same package as all the other classes.

Comment: It seems to me like you are writing to the wrong file. Why are you accessing the read file from the classpath but the write file from the file system?

Comment: They are both the same file anyway. Just something I forgot to change. They're now both from classpath.

Comment: Please update your code and tell us from which directory you are running the application.

Comment: I'm running it in netbeans.

Comment: It's not the same file if you read from classpath and write to filesystem.

Comment: Ask yourself: where is the file you are reading from and writing to?

Comment: It is in a package called loginform and the file is called users.DAT. In netbeans it is the same place whether gotten from the classpath or filesystem but if I ran it outside netbeans it wouldn't work. Well thats what I thought anyway. What file would it be writing to if not the one it's reading to? Wouldn't there be an error if the file didn't exist?

Comment: Do a `System.out.println(<your-file-object>.getAbsolutePath())` when reading and when writing and you'll find out whether your dealing with the same file or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your reading you use `file = Board.class.getResourceAsStream("users.DAT");` in your writing you just create a file new `File("users.DAT")` what about changing your `addUser()` to

```
public void addUser() throws IOException {
       fileWriter = new FileWriter(Board.class.getResource("users.DAT").getFile());
       ....
}
```

**Edit**: The problem is that during writing you are not retrieving the same file as before. I would add this method

```
public File getUserDataFile() {
    return new File(Board.class.getResource("").getFile(), "users.DATA");
}
// then use it like this
new FileWriter(getUserDataFile());
// and
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getUserDataFile()));
```

then access it whenever you want to read and write to your file. The problem is `Board.class.getResourceAsStream("users.DAT")` will return null if your file doesnt exist.

Comment: Tried this but had no effect still.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have packaged your jar with some state of the file `users.DAT` (a defined set of users) and when you read them from classpath you see only the users from the time you have created the jar. The writing goes then to another file.

You should read the user from the filesystem too.

Check the working directory of your app there should be correct file containing the users added.

Also no need for copying all the user over and over again every time you add one, just open your file in append mode

```
fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("users.DAT"), true);
```

Unless you want to be able to delete users, in that case keep everything in memory and save when you exit the program or explicitly with a save action.